Android Studio SDK 34 get bitmap of full image from camera intent
I am trying to obtain the bitmap of the full size image resulting from an intent, with the following i only obtain de bitmap of the thumbnail.
//------- START CAMERA --------------


public void onClickBtn(View v) {

vibe.vibrate(100);

Intent camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(camera_intent, pic_id);
}



protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode == pic_id) {
    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    click_image_id.setImageBitmap(photo);

    //------------------------------

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();

    String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);


    editor.putString("img", encoded);
    editor.apply();

}
}

This is for SDK 34 with the following setup:
Android Studio Koala Feature Drop | 2024.1.2
Build #AI-241.18034.62.2412.12266719, built on August 22, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.11+0--11852314 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10.0

https://developer.android.com/media/camera/camera-deprecated/photobasics#TaskPath
